# Classify partial differential equation...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I.e. The order and whether it is linear, semi-linear, quasi-linear or fully non-linear.

Would be great if anyone could check if I'm doing this right.. Bit confused with the domain, is it relevant for classifying? Thanks

Questions:

1)
$ u_t+u_{xxx}+u^2u_{xx}=0 $ for $u(x,t)$ defined on $\Bbb R \times (0,\infty)$

2)
$(u_t + u)(u_{xxx} + u_{xx}) = 0$ for $u(x,t)$ defined on $\Bbb R \times (0,\infty)$

3) $(\Delta u)^2=f$ for $u(x)$ defined on $\Bbb R^n,n\ge 2$, and $f(x)$ defined on $\Bbb R^n$

My answers:

1) Third order, semi-linear

2) Third order, quasi-linear

3) Second order, fully non-linear (?)

Does $(\Delta u)^2=(u_{xx})^2$ ?

Comment: $\Delta u$ is the Laplacian, e.g. $u_{xx} + u_{yy} + u_{zz}$ if $n=3$.

Answer (score 1):

1) 1st order quasi-linear (see, e.g., [this](http://math.stanford.edu/~andras/220-2.pdf))

2) 4th order quasi-linear ((see, e.g., [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveLinearAndQuasiLinearFirstOrderPDEs.html))

3) correct